# PowerShell XML Output

Tags: xml, powershell, parsing

I'm having trouble getting the desired results in the correct format with this **PowerShell** query when run against an XML file exported from **Task Scheduler**. I will eventually have this run against all **Task Scheduler** exported jobs dumped to the same one XML file but I'm starting with just one for now.

**PowerShell Logic** *(not working)*

```
$file = "C:\folder\test.xml"
$Xml  = [xml](Get-Content $file)
$Xml.SelectNodes("//*").ChildNodes | Select URI,Command | 
Where-Object { ($_.URI -ne $null) -or ($_.Command -ne $null) } | FL
```

Perhaps there's a better or more explicit way of doing this with **PowerShell** in a loop or embedding some **C#** code and executing that with PowerShell, etc. I figured I'd ask others here since I cannot get this figured out after a ton of testing and research but I'm open to all ideas to help me get the desired result or something similar (see below). If I needed the result from **SQL Server** I'd use `FOR XML PATH`.

---

**Current Result Format** *(not desired)*

```
URI     : \_Test\Test
Command : 

URI     : 
Command : C:\Folder\process1.exe

URI     : 
Command : C:\Folder\process2.exe
```

**Desired Result Format** *(or similar)*

```
URI     : \_Test\Test
Command : C:\Folder\process1.exe
Command : C:\Folder\process2.exe
```

---

**Sample XML**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2017-03-09T09:36:56.2658334</Date>
    <Author>FBI-PC1\User</Author>
    <URI>\_Test\Test</URI>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers />
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>S-1-5-21-3517161704-4063526634-2635523359-1001</UserId>
      <LogonType>InteractiveToken</LogonType>
      <RunLevel>LeastPrivilege</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>true</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT72H</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>C:\Folder\process1.exe</Command>
    </Exec>
    <Exec>
      <Command>C:\Folder\process2.exe</Command>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

---

**System Specs** *(needs to work with)*

- **Windows 7**
- **PowerShell V 4.0**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are selecting both the objects together applying the where condition, so for maintaining the equality as a single object, it is showing like that .

In your case what you can do is to store the resultant in *arraylist* and do the manipulation there for all the *Commands* what you are getting like :

```
$file = "C:\folder\test.xml"
$Xml  = [xml](Get-Content $file)
$URI= $Xml.SelectNodes("//*").ChildNodes | Select URI| Where-Object { $_.URI -ne $null}
$Command= $Xml.SelectNodes("//*").ChildNodes | Select Command| Where-Object { $_.Command -ne $null}

$arraylisttable = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$arraylisttable.Add($URI)  | Out-Null

foreach($cmd in $Command)
{
$arraylisttable.Add($Cmd) | Out-Null
}
$arraylisttable | fl
```

***OUTPUT:***

[image: Result]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

```
$Xml.SelectNodes("//*[local-name()='Command' or local-name()='URI']") | select Name, "#text"

Name    #text
----    -----
URI     \_Test\Test
Command C:\Folder\process1.exe
Command C:\Folder\process2.exe
```

This way you move selection logic to Xpath. Things to note:

- `//*` selects all nodes
- text inside `[]` is an XPath filter criteria.
- using `local-name()` XPath function is a trick to avoid messing with namespaces

Note that XPath comparisons are case sensitive. Unfortunately XPath 1.0 does not have `lower-case()` or the like function. To make case-insensitive comparison (as Powershell does) use `translate()` function:

```
$Xml.SelectNodes("//*[translate(local-name(), 'COMAND', 'comand')='command' or translate(local-name(), 'uri', 'URI')='URI']") | select Name, "#text"
```

If you prefer pure Powershell over XPath here is alternate solution:

```
$xml.SelectNodes('//*') | ? {$_.Name -in ('command', 'uri')} | select Name, "#text"
```

One more thing *about tasks*. You do not have to *dump* them. They natively reside as xml already in the`C:\Windows\Tasks` or
`C:\Windows\System32\Tasks` folders depending on the OS. For Win7 it is `C:\Windows\System32\Tasks`. You would need admin access to read them.

**Edit:** To get *exactly* the same output:

```
$xml.SelectNodes('//*') | ? { $_.Name -in ('command', 'uri') } |
 select Name, @{Name = 'Value'; Expression = {": $($_.'#text')" } } |
 ft -HideTableHeaders

URI     : \_Test\Test
Command : C:\Folder\process1.exe
Command : C:\Folder\process2.exe
```

**Custom object:**

```
$customObject = [pscustomObject]@{
    URI = ($xml.SelectNodes("//*[local-name()='URI']")).'#text'
    Command = ($xml.SelectNodes("//*[local-name()='Command']")).'#text'
}
$customObject | fl

URI     : \_Test\Test
Command : {C:\Folder\process1.exe, C:\Folder\process2.exe}
```

Comment: @MagicallyDelicous No problem, I have updated my answer just for the case.